# Invalid Uri : The uri scheme is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to login to a website via WebRequest. I get an exception at this point :

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl.Trim());
```

`string url,string username,string password` come from a text box. This is the full code:

```
public void LoginToUrl(string url,string username, string password )
{
    formUrl = url;
    formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username,password);                  

    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl.Trim());//
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
      bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
}
```

This is the POST Data:

```
Host=internetlogin1.cu.edu.ng

User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0

Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
```

Refer this [link](https://internetlogin1.cu.edu.ng/login)

```
Connection=keep-alive

Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length=49
POSTDATA=dst=&popup=true&username=13ck015373&password=F3NB
```

Comment: Well, how does the URL look like?

Comment: https://internetlogin1.cu.edu.ng/login      its only accessible through my schools intranet

Comment: In the browser, press  F12 and use the debugger to check exactly what is being posted. Add this to your question.

Comment: Clearly that is not the full URL as you are adding parameters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should pass a valid URL to create a WebRequest.
The error says that URL (that comes from textbox) dose not contains scheme ('http://' or 'https://') or it is invalid.

Enter this URL in text-box (don't forget http or https):

http://internetlogin1.cu.edu.ng  or  https://internetlogin1.cu.edu.ng

Comment: This is the form: https://imageshack.com/i/plrZ2PWvp                         and this is the Error  https://imageshack.com/i/pnxf7Omjp

Comment: @simdiejinkeonye: According to error image, you have an error on passing text-box values to LoginToUrl function. Assume URL text-box is txtUrl, you should use txtUrl.Text to reference the value entered in the form.

Comment: @simdiejinkeonye  Talebian is right. The problem we can see in the error image is in the call to LoginToUrl. You are passing the TextBoxes as parameters, instead of each TextBox.Text..

Answer (score 2):

I had a schema uri invalid issue as well.  Had to do the following for it to work.  Not sure why.. but fyi

Works:

```
Uri serverUri = new Uri("http://url.com/sub/somethingService");
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
```

What did not work (had this same error):

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url.com/sub/somethingService");
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are the parameters of url-string then you need to add them through '?' and '&' chars

Answer (score 0):

please add 'http://' or 'https://' to your url or check that not have ("") 
for example "http://YourUrl:YourPort" is not correct  and should replace to http://YourUrl:YourPort . you enter your url into notepad to you find problem