# VSTO Outlook Addin Installer Project

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I basically followed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019
to create msi installer.
the install goes well and I see registry value. However, Outlook shows the add-in inactive and cannot even shows up on diabled COM plugin. Any advice is appreciated.
I am on Visual Studio 2017 and Outlook 2016 32bit.

Thank you!

Outlook loads plugin as active is the ideal.

Update:

Log shows
Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
'''

```
************** Exception Text **************

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, Boolean useFastPath, IntPtr& executor)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IDomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomain(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
```

Does this mean required component missing?

Thank you,

Comment: Registry, Loadbehavior becomes 2 from 3 when I run it.

Comment: I'd suggest searching for similar issues before posting, see [Invalid Uri : The uri scheme is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456625/invalid-uri-the-uri-scheme-is-not-valid).

Comment: The thing is that I did not use those functions in my code.

Comment: When and where do you get this exception thrown?

Comment: At the time of start up, and when I tried to enable from COM Add-in window. Thank you,

Comment: Do you get anything like that with a newly created add-in project? Does it work correctly?

Comment: OK, I will try create project from scratch. Thank you,

Comment: I worked when I created brand new project!
I found one dependency,was accidentally excluded.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the application successfully loads the VSTO add-in, the `LoadBehavior` value changes to 3, and remains at 3 after the application closes.

There are multiple reasons why Outlook may disable your add-in. Just some of them are listed below:

1. Unhandled exceptions at runtime.
2. Any prerequisite is missing on the end-user machine.
3. The add-in doesn't correspond to the performance criteria that Outlook applies to add-ins.

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2022) for more information.

The `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` Windows environment variable can be set for enabling detailed VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) error messages when loading VSTO add-ins.

Comment: I enabled VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS, however, nothing come up and cannot try enable addin since the addin is not in the list of COM Add-ins window.

Comment: Well, you need to check windows registry keys for the add-in then.

Comment: Managed to get error and pasted in original post as update.
Thanks,

Comment: See [Invalid Uri : The uri scheme is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456625/invalid-uri-the-uri-scheme-is-not-valid)